# How to select ul's specific li child text using Scrapy's css or xpath selector?

Tags: jquery, html, css, xpath, css-selectors

Below is the HTML, I am working on:

```
<div class="grdcpnsmllnks">
    <ul>
        <li><i class="fa fa-check-square"></i>Verified Offer</li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-eye"></i><label id="ltveri276270">Offer used 1 hour ago</label></li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>Valid till 31/12/2016</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Below is my code snippet:

```
def parse_item(self, response):
    endDate = response.xpath('//div[@class='grdcpnsmllnks']/ul/li/i[@class='fa-clock-o']::dd[1]/text()').extract()
        yield {
            'endDate': endDate
        }
```

I wish to select the text Valid till 31/12/2016. I am having trouble in first selecting the required `<li>` tag and then further select the text which is not contained inside any tag. Kindly suggest me how to do that using xpath or css selector.

Answer (score 0):

I'd locate the `li` element by checking the existence of a child `i` element which *contains* `fa-clock-o` class attribute, then get the direct child `text()` node and then use `.re_first()` method to extract the date:

```
In [1]: response.xpath("//div[@class='grdcpnsmllnks']//li[i[contains(@class, 'fa-clock-o')]]/text()").re_first(r"Valid till\s+(\d+/\d+/\d+)")
Out[1]: u'31/12/2016'
```

Comment: When I use the above command with .extract(), it gives an Attribute Error: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'extract()'

Comment: @AmanAgarwal it's already extracted by `re_first()` no need to call extra `extract()`.

Comment: But even then it is not giving the value, it is giving 'None'.

Comment: @AmanAgarwal well, I've copied your HTML and run it through the `scrapy shell` - works for me. Check if you really have this input HTML you parse with Scrapy.

Comment: def parse_item(self, response):
 
     title = response.css('.nw-merbrdrdbx .nw-offrtxt a .ofr-descptxt::text').extract()
        description = response.css('.nw-merbrdrdbx .nw-offrtxt .merdl-descp span::text').extract()
       
        endDate = response.xpath("//div[@class='nw-merbrdrdbx']//div[@class='grdcpnsmllnks']//li[i[contains(@class, 'fa-clock-o')]]/text()").re_first(r"Valid till\s+(\d+/\d+/\d+)")
        
        merchant = response.css('.visit a span::text').extract()
        imageUrl = response.css('.nw-merbrdrdbx .ofrpctg img::attr(src)').extract()

Comment: city = response.css('.nw-merbrdrdbx .nw-offrtxt .cat-tags::text').extract()
       for title, description, imageUrl, endDate in map(None, title, description, imageUrl, endDate):
      if (title):
          yield {
            'merchant': merchant,
            'title': title,
            'description': description,
            'endDate': endDate,
            'imageUrl': imageUrl,
            
           }

The last and this comments are in continuation and form my complete code.

Comment: @AmanAgarwal well, that does not help much. Edit the question and provide the complete code you have so far. Thanks.